# Convert std::string to std::chrono::duration

Tags: c++, duration, c++-chrono

My goal is to convert one single `string` in the form `"%H:%M:%S"` to `chrono::duration` in `C++11`.

As an example, in order to convert `"00:15:00"`,
I came up with the following indirect solution where I calculate two timepoints (1) `"00:15:00"` and (2) `"00:00:00"`, which are with respect to the `system_clock` or `steady_clock`:  I then subtract them from each other to get the duration.

```
std::tm tm0 = {}, tm1{};
std::stringstream ss0("00:00:00"), ss1("00:15:00");
ss0 >> std::get_time(&tm0, "%H:%M:%S");
ss1 >> std::get_time(&tm1, "%H:%M:%S");
auto t0 = std::chrono::system_clock::from_time_t(std::mktime(&tm0));
auto t1 = std::chrono::system_clock::from_time_t(std::mktime(&tm1));
auto d = t1-t0;
std::cout << std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::seconds>(d).count();
```

It does the conversion but I was wondering if there is an elegant way or direct way of achieving this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your current solution has the potential to very rarely give you incorrect answers.  If your two local times happen to straddle a UTC offset change in your local time zone (e.g. a daylight saving shift), then the amount of that shift is going to be included in the subtraction, subsequently giving you the wrong answer.

I recommend doing your own parsing to get the value of hours, minutes and seconds into `int`s:

```
int h0, h1;
int m0, m1;
int s0, s1;
```

and then you can very simply convert them to the proper units and add/subtract them:

```
auto d = (hours{h1} + minutes{m1} + seconds{s1})
       - (hours{h0} + minutes{m0} + seconds{s0});
```

The type of `d` is `seconds`.

You have several options for parsing in C++11, and here is one of the simplest:

```
ss0 >> h0 >> c >> m0 >> c >> s0;
ss1 >> h1 >> c >> m1 >> c >> s1;
```

(where `c` is a `char` to parse the `:`)

In C++20 there will be a `std::chrono::parse` function that can be used like this:

```
seconds d;
ss0 >> parse("%H:%M:%S", d);
```

Or one can use `"%T"` as a shortcut for `"%H:%M:%S"`.  I mention this knowing you are using C++11, not C++20. But there exists a [free, open-source preview of C++20 chrono](https://github.com/HowardHinnant/date) that works with C++11/14/17.  For this part, you only need the header date.h, which is a header-only library.

```
#include "date/date.h"

// ...

seconds d;
ss0 >> date::parse("%T", d);
```

Comment: And of course, the stream needs to have its base set to 10 (which is luckily the default), not 0/unset, because these input strings will frequently contain leading zeros.

Comment: Agreed.  In my answer `sso` and `ss1` are assumed to have the same type and value as they do in the question.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I am trying to convert a single string in the form `%H:%M:%S` to `chrono::duration`. Is there a direct way of doing this conversion?

Comment: I've updated my answer with a free, open-source, header-only library that will do the parse and addition for you.